# How do I implement some sort of sessions in my bot?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am using Microsoft Bot Framework SDK 4 Node JS, to be deployed on Skype. I want to implement some sort of sessioning in my bot. For example if the user has not interacted with the bot in 'x' amount of time then the conversation would end.

Currently I use the 'onMessage' function to update a variable each time the user sends a message to the bot and compare that time against the last time the user interacted. If it exceeds the time limit then the conversation ends.

But the problem is, this method does not work for more than 1 user. So if 2 people are interacting with the bot, the timer variable gets updated every time any of those users interact with the bot.

However, I want to create a new instance of this timer variable for each user and update it when that particular user interacts with the bot.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use state management for this purpose as per the quoted part from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript) below:

> A bot is inherently stateless. Once your bot is deployed, it may not
>   run in the same process or on the same machine from one turn to the
>   next. However, your bot may need to track the context of a
>   conversation so that it can manage its behavior and remember answers
>   to previous questions. The state and storage features of the Bot
>   Framework SDK allow you to add state to your bot. Bots use state
>   management and storage objects to manage and persist state. The state
>   manager provides an abstraction layer that lets you access state
>   properties using property accessors, independent of the type of
>   underlying storage.

This is mainly based on using 2 objects, which are `UserState` and `ConversationState` and `MemoryStorage` to simulate storage.

Here's an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript) illustrating their use after defining classes and creating objects:

```
// The accessor names for the conversation data and user profile state property accessors.
const CONVERSATION_DATA_PROPERTY = 'conversationData';
const USER_PROFILE_PROPERTY = 'userProfile';

class StateManagementBot extends ActivityHandler {
    constructor(conversationState, userState) {
        super();
        // Create the state property accessors for the conversation data and user profile.
        this.conversationData = conversationState.createProperty(CONVERSATION_DATA_PROPERTY);
        this.userProfile = userState.createProperty(USER_PROFILE_PROPERTY);

        // The state management objects for the conversation and user state.
        this.conversationState = conversationState;
        this.userState = userState;
```

Then you can easily use the accessors at run-time to read and write state information.

You can also check the [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/45.state-management) mentioned in the documentation for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Ali's answer a little...

Using a timeout to end the conversation is not a good practice because when you scale out messages may be routed to different instances of the bot and the timeout won't be canceled correctly. A better approach is to save the last time the user messaged the bot in userState and check the time difference the next time the user messages the bot before responding. Take a look at the code snippets below.

```
const TIMEOUT = 5000;



  // Prompts
  async promptForName(step) {
    this.profileAccessor.set(step.context, { lastMessage: new Date() });    
    return await step.prompt(NAME_PROMPT, "What is your name?");
  }

  async captureName(step) {
    const profile = await this.profileAccessor.get(step.context);
    if (new Date().getTime() - new Date(profile.lastMessage).getTime() < TIMEOUT) {
      profile.name = step.result;
      profile.lastMessage = new Date();
      this.profileAccessor.set(step.context, profile);

      await this.userState.saveChanges(step.context);

      return await step.next();
    } else {
      await step.context.sendActivity("Sorry, you took too long to respond");
      return await step.endDialog();
    }
  }
```